# how to remove the documents of mongo database from shell script file

Tags: linux, mongodb, shell, sh

I would like to remove some documents of mongo database from shell script file by using some query.

I use the following command, but this doesn't work.

```
mongo dbName --eval "db.collection.remove({"param1":"value"})"
```

How should I delete the documents from mongo database from shell script by command line ??

Comment: Try this db.collection.remove({"param1":"value"},true)

Comment: I beleive it is your use of `"`, the bash script is being confused, try something like `"db.collection.remove({param1:'value'})"`

Answer (score 6):

Your command line use both double quotes for shell strings, as well as string delimiters in the string itself. This causes confusion to the shell. You can either escape your " in the string:

```
mongo dbName --eval "db.collection.remove({\"param1\":\"value\"})"
```

Or use single quotes, like:

```
mongo dbName --eval 'db.collection.remove({"param1":"value"})"'
```

I would suggest you use single quotes around the whole string, instead of using single quotes *in* the string, as this also means that strings that contain an `$` are not interpolated or cause other issues.